# Is it a good idea to first train a spiking neural network and then convert it to a conventional neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, biology, spiking-neural-networks

In many papers about artificial spiking neural networks (SNNs), the performance of them is not up to par with traditional ANNs. I have read how some people have converted ANNs to SNNs using various techniques.

There has been work done on using unsupervised learning in SNN to recognise MNIST digits through [spike-timing-dependent plasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike-timing-dependent_plasticity) (for example, the paper [Unsupervised learning of digit recognition using spike-timing-dependent plasticity](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fncom.2015.00099/full), by Diehl and Cook, 2015). This form of learning is not possible in traditional ANNs due to their synchronous nature.

I was wondering would it be a good idea to first train an SNN in an unsupervised manner to learn some of the structure of the data. Then convert to a traditional ANN to take advantage of their superior performance with some more training. I can see this being useful for training a network on a sparsely labelled dataset.

I am quite a novice in this area, so I was looking for feedback on any immediate barriers as to why this would not work or if it is even worth doing.